# Convergence in Probability of a sum

Tags: probability, convergence

What are the minimum details that i need to know in order to find the limit in probability of a specific random variable (such as the sum of several random variables)?

For example, suppose i have a sequence of random variables: $X_{1}, X_{2},...,X_{n}$ and i know that: $E(X_{i}) = \mu$ and $Var(X_{i}) = \sigma$ but i dont know which particular distribution has every $X_{i}$.
I can argue that from the Weak Law of Large Numbers, $\bar{X} = \frac {\sum X_{n}}{n}$ converges in probability to $\mu$.

But my question is, can i say anything about the convergence in probability of $\sum X_{n}$???

What else do i need to state something about the convergence of $\sum X_{n}$ ?
Thank's!

Comment: Lookup Kolmogorov's "Two series" and "Three Series" theorems for two sets of conditions needed to obtain almost sure convergence of the sum of independent r.v's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'll re-cast the variance to standard notation: $Var(X_i) = \sigma^2$.

If $\sigma^2>0$ and the $X_i$ are independent, then we can show that $\sum X_i$ diverges almost surely...

$$\sigma > 0 \implies \exists \epsilon>0: P(|X_i|\geq\epsilon)>0\;\;\forall i\; $$

We know this because each variable is forced to have the same variance. Therefore, the smallest allowable $\epsilon$ is fixed above zero. We can find this value by assuming $X_i$ follows a shifted and scaled Bernoulli(0.5) r.v.:

$$X_i = s\times(Y_i-0.5),\;\;Y_i\sim Ber(0.5) :$$

Here, 
$$Var(X_i) = \left(\frac{s}{2}\right)^2 = \sigma^2 \implies s=2\sigma \implies \min \epsilon = \sigma$$

Now, $E_k := |X_k|\geq\epsilon$, then

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum P(E_k) = \infty$$

If we assume the $E_i$ are independent, then we can then use the [partial converse Borel-Cantelli Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma#Converse_result), to conclude that $E_i$ happens infinitely often, hence the sum will not converge (the sum will just keep moving around, since the $X_i \not \rightarrow 0\;$)

An alternative approach, which just establishes divergence *in probability* if $X_i$ are independent is as follows:

$$S_k = \sum_1^k X_i \implies Var(S_k) = k\sigma^2 \implies P(|S_k|\geq \sqrt{k}\sigma) > 0$$